# Is there a trick to execute Seth's Head Stomps?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I struggle with the execution of Seth's corner combo Spin Kicks into Head Stomps.

As the initial part of the combo does not matter lets assume I want to do this:

**(corner) HK.Kicks HS HS HS DK**

Kicks = Spin Kicks, HS = Head Stomp, DK = Dive Kick

Currently I press diagonally forward up after the Kicks and "guess" when to switch to down or down forward + MK. It works sometimes, but most of the time I either press down forward too fast (result: c.MK), too slow (result: whiff) or MK too fast (result: j.MK).

Is there some trick like double tapping or pliking to make this combo easier? Is there some easy way to learn the timing except just executing it over and over again?

Comment: Note that you can only get two head stomps on some characters.

Comment: @Decency This is late, but you can get three head stomps on any character, provided you launch the opponent using his QCBM kick, Hyakuretsukyaku.  Check out a player named Poongko, he's amazing with Seth (pre-Ultra)